# Using FIND query on Salesforce Report Object

Tags: reporting, folder, reports-folder

I am trying to filter my reports using this query [FIND 'test' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Report(Id, Name, Description, FolderName, LastRunDate, CreatedDate)].

The FolderName for one of my reports is test, but when I run this query it doesn't return anything. Why isn't it able to filter on that field? Do filters work on dates also?

Comment: looks like field is not searchable https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields.htm&type=0

Comment: You can do a regular SOQL : `SELECT Id, Name, FolderName FROM Report WHERE FolderName LIKE '%test%'`